# GDAL concatenating vrts

Tags: gdal, vrt, gdalbuildvrt

I'd like to concatenate a few vrts together. So i have three vrts representing data from different years and to make my life easier would like just to have one vrt created from the three vrts.

Each of the vrts has 365 bands, and i want the outputted vrt to be the stacking of these bands so (3*365) bands.

```
<VRTDataset rasterXSize="2400" rasterYSize="2400">
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="UInt16" band="1">
   [from 2007.vrt]
  </VRTRasterBand>
    ...
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="UInt16" band="365">
    [from 2007.vrt]
    </VRTRasterBand>
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="UInt16" band="366">
    [from 2008.vrt]
  </VRTRasterBand>
    ...
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="UInt16" band="730">
    [from 2008.vrt]
  </VRTRasterBand>
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="UInt16" band="731">
   [from 2009.vrt]
  </VRTRasterBand>
   ...
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="UInt16" band="1095">
   [from 2009.vrt]
  </VRTRasterBand>
</VRTDataset >
```

I was hoping something like:

```
gdalbuildvrt 2007_2009.vrt 200{7,8,9}.vrt
```

would work. But this unfortunately not. Instead of stacking as above i get:

```
<VRTDataset rasterXSize="2400" rasterYSize="2400">
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="UInt16" band="1">
   [from 2007.vrt band 1]
   [from 2008.vrt band 1]
   [from 2009.vrt band 1]
  </VRTRasterBand>
    ...
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="UInt16" band="N">
   [from 2007.vrt band N]
   [from 2008.vrt band N]
   [from 2009.vrt band N]
  </VRTRasterBand>
</VRTDataset >
```

which `gdalinfo` only records as 365 bands.

Pictorially 2007_2009.vrt would be constructed like:

```
2007_2009.vrt-|
             -- 2007.vrt
             -- 2008.vrt
             -- 2009.vrt
```

I'm on a unix system

Comment: hi Luke, I've edited my question. I'm on a Unix system. There is no error  message it just the output vrt is not a concatenated version of the inputs. I tried the -separate option but this just used the first file.